# Why does this Haskell expression compile?

Tags: haskell, typechecking, phantom-types

Here are some definitions I wrote, to avoid mixing currencies

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

data EUR
data USD 

newtype Amount a = Amount Double deriving (Fractional, Num, Show)

eur :: Double -> Amount EUR
eur = Amount

usd :: Double -> Amount USD
usd = Amount
```

- `usd 34 + usd 3` type checks as expected
- `usd 33 + eur 33` is a compilation error as expected
- I'm surprised but `usd 33 + 3` is OK according to the compiler. Something I wanted to avoid, and don't understand. I suspect it is because `Num` instance, but then what is the difference with the second case?

Can you explain why `usd 33 + 3` compiles and if it is possible to make the type-checker reject this expression.

Comment: The `Num` type class is _not_ [for "things that can be added"](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector-space/latest/doc/html/Data-AdditiveGroup.html#t:AdditiveGroup). It's for data types that encompass, possibly amongst other values, the integral numbers, and support the primitive numerical operations in a way that's compatible with those numbers.

Comment: Exactly.  So what you really want is a "math symbols" class or classes (Add, Subtract, Multiply, Divide, etc).  Lots of EDSLs define their own infix operators, such as `.+`, `.-`, and `.*` in order to avoid using the cludgy `Num` class.

Comment: I'm not sure this is really a fatal problem, though. In practice, it turns out to matter very rarely that you can have literals of your custom type, since they still aren't polymorphic unless declared as such.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Numbers in Haskell have lots of implicitness. Mentally, you ought to replace every number literal like `3` with `fromInteger 3`. Since `Amount` uses `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` to be part of the `Num` typeclass, it inherits a `fromInteger` instance. So the compiler is doing this

```
usd 33 + 3
===                                      [implicit fromInteger & expand usd]
(Amount 33 :: Amount USD) + 
  fromInteger 3
===                                      [fromInteger :: Num a => a -> Amount a]
(Amount 33 :: Amount USD) + 
  (Amount 3 :: Amount a)
===                                      [unify a]
(Amount 33 :: Amount USD) + 
  (Amount 3 :: Amount USD)
```

Answer (score 2):

When GHC derives the `Num` class, it provides an implementation for the
`fromInteger` function. Integer literals like `3` actually have the type `Num a => a`.

```
ghci> :t (34)
(34) :: Num a => a
```

When the type checker sees that you are trying to add a value of type
`Amount USD` to `3`, it determines `3 :: Amount USD`, which is valid since
it is a member of the `Num` typeclass.

Comment: What is that `∀ x. x ⊦ ...` bit?

Comment: @tel, that is my GHCI prompt. I can see where that would be confusing.